# Matplotlib Dashboard with multiple gridspecs and horizontal and vertical adjacencies

Tags: python, matplotlib

A supplemental question to the recent clarification of adjacencies. I know what I need to achieve but being relatively new to python/matplotlib I am somewhat lost.

As per title - I am trying to produce a dashboard layout that includes both horizontal and vertical adjacencies. As per guidance from earlier questions - I have an outer gridspec and 3 inner gridspecs (gs0, gs1 & gs2).

My challenge is the middle spec - gs1. I am needing to produce 2 vertical charts (on the LHS of the row) and a single polar chart that spans 2 rows on the RHS. My challenge is how to merge the 2 cells into a single ax and importantly what is the right way to create such a complex layout.

Thanks in advance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

def example_plot(ax):
    ax.plot([1, 2])
    ax.set_xlabel('x-label', fontsize=12)
    ax.set_ylabel('y-label', fontsize=12)
    ax.set_title('Title', fontsize=14)

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=False)

outer_gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=3, ncols=1, figure=fig, height_ratios=[5,2,2], wspace=0.2,  hspace=0.3)
gs0 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(nrows=3, ncols=1, subplot_spec=outer_gs[0], height_ratios=[1,4,1], wspace=0.2, hspace=0)
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(nrows=2, ncols=2, subplot_spec=outer_gs[1], width_ratios=[5,2], wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)
gs2 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(nrows=1, ncols=5, subplot_spec=outer_gs[2], wspace=0, hspace=0.3)

# Top 3 adjacent charts
for n in range(3):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[n])
    example_plot(ax)

# Middle bit - 2 horizontal plots and polar chart on RHS (spanning both rows)

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[0])
example_plot(ax4)

ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[1])
example_plot(ax5)

ax6 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[2])
example_plot(ax6)

ax7 = fig.add_subplot(gs1[3])
example_plot(ax7)


# Bottom 5 dials
for n in range(5):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs2[n])
    example_plot(ax)
```

[target dashboard layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHBFu.png)

Comment: You can keep nesting the GridSpec to another level.

Comment: Ok Jody - thanks makes sense and got me 95% home. A side effect of the additional layer seems to be a set of Axis around the entire plot?

Comment: As per:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8), constrained_layout=False )   # a figure with a 2x2 grid of Axes
outer_gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2,1, height_ratios=[5,2], wspace=0.2, hspace=0.6)
upper_gs = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(4,1, subplot_spec=outer_gs[0], height_ratios=[3,3,3,2], wspace=0.2, hspace=0)
lower_gs = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1,2, subplot_spec=outer_gs[1], width_ratios=[4,1], wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)
lower_left_gs = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2,1, subplot_spec=lower_gs[0], wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)